# CakePHP Associations - hasMany but need to match column in 3rd table?

Tags: php, cakephp, associations

I am new to CakePHP (2.x) and am creating a post and comments feature. Everything works except I cannot figure out how to get the user's username out of the registrations (third) table (linked with "registration_id"). My associations currently look like:

```
class Article extends AppModel {

public $hasMany = array('ArticleComment');

public $belongsTo = array(
    'ArticleRegistration' => array(
        'className' => 'Registration',
        'foreignKey' => 'Article.registration_id'    //(doesn't work)
    ),
    'ArticleCommentRegistration' => array(
        'className' => 'Registration',
        'foreignKey' => 'ArticleComment.registration_id'    //(doesn't work)
    )
);

class ArticleComment extends AppModel {
public $belongsTo = array('Registration','Article');
```

I am not sure if the associations from ArticleComment are being applied since it  is being called through the Article model. I am retrieving the data by:

```
$this->set('articles', $this->Article->find('all', array('order' => 'Article.created desc', 'limit' => '3')));
```

I have tried a join and passing two separate variables for the articles and comments array but then I have to remove my associations which leads me to believe it's not proper coding.

Tables are:

```
articles
__________
id
registration_id
body

article_comments
__________
id
article_id
registration_id
body

registration
__________
id
username
```

I am fetching the information with:

```
$this->set('articles', $this->Article->find('all', array('order' => 'Article.created desc')));
```

TIA!

Answer (score 0):

The generated SQL query from cakephp when you make a `find()` call is as follows

```
SELECT `Article`.`id`,
       `Article`.`registration_id`,
       `Article`.`body`,
       `Registration`.`id`,
       `Registration`.`username` 
FROM `test`.`articles` AS `Article` 
      LEFT JOIN `test`.`registration` AS `Registration` 
      ON (`Article`.`registration_id` = `Registration`.`id`) 
WHERE 1 = 1 LIMIT 20
```

So, in order to access the username you just need to write something like this in your view

```
$articles['Registration']['username'];
```

I recommend you to use the cakephp  bake commands, I could make this proyect like in 10 minutes with them. And also I recommend using Netbeans as IDE, the cakephp plugin is awesome.

Here is a [link](https://bitbucket.org/pabloFloresHdz/articlescakephp) to an example project that you can clone with git.